# Disable Elasticsearch 8.X authentication

Tags: java, elasticsearch, elastic-stack, elk

I have installed the latest version on elasticsearch on my raspberry pi by following

https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/deb.html

When I do curl it asks me for password

[image]

Here is service status of my elasticsearch

[image]

I even disable elasticsearch security in yaml file .

```
#http.enabled: false

xpack.security.enabled: false
xpack.security.http.ssl.enabled: false
xpack.security.transport.ssl.enabled: false
```

When I did restart of elasticsearch it still asks me for password . IS there a way to disable authentication where I can access elasticsearch with curl directly ?

Below is my elasticsearch service status

[image]

Below is process

[image]

Comment: What happens is you hit `http` instead of `https` after restarting? Since security is disabled, there's no https endpoint anymore. The command should just be `curl http://localhost.9200`, no `https` no `-u`

Answer (score -1):

You can either set `xpack.security.enabled: false` before starting Elasticsearch for the first time. So in your case, you could purge the installation (since I don't assume you have any relevant data in it yet), reinstall it, change the setting, and then start Elasticsearch for the first time.

For an existing cluster, you can IMO stop it and run the following commands:

```
bin/elasticsearch-keystore remove xpack.security.transport.ssl.keystore.secure_password
bin/elasticsearch-keystore remove xpack.security.transport.ssl.truststore.secure_password
bin/elasticsearch-keystore remove xpack.security.http.ssl.keystore.secure_password
```

Then set `xpack.security.enabled: false` and then start Elasticsearch again.

PS: Security by default is strongly recommended. Lots of leaked data in the past so we would really recommend to keep it enabled :)

Comment: I did set xpack-servuce-enabled as false and restarted it but still it asks for authentication . This is just for my local personal home project and es is on my raspberyy pi .

Comment: "before starting Elasticsearch for the first time". Either wipe the installation and apply that setting or follow the second half of the post with all the steps. Please read the full post again.